# Sliding in Panel - JQuery Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, panel

I am trying to add into my website (Magento Store) a slide in panel (https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-slide-in-panel/) and I am getting issues when including the JQuery.js file. It complains about not finding a particular function for other extensions. The result I could only find is that it is a common issue called JS conflict. I am newbie and any help will be appreciated.

List of errors:

```
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
extendedreviews.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).hoverIntent is not a function
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
somesome.com/:777 Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).foundation is not a function
prototype.js:5734 Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

I am including the JS for this panel in head file as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slidein/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slidein/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slidein/main.js"></script>
```

Note that, before these 3 includes, there are many other JS included for third party extensions. The errors are related to files for these third party extensions

Comment: Are you able to post more information? Like the error, perhaps a snippet of code? Have you managed to localise the issue?

Comment: I will post more info now but we can think of it in general. If I have a site wher eit heavily make use of java scripts jquery etc (Magento Store). and If I am about to include/import a new JS file, what do I expect? what should I pay an attention to? such as JS conflict.

Comment: Order of inclusion is important. IE: in which order you including the scripts, and if your Magento deployment does not already have jQuery included etc. It's important to understand your error, and see some examples. If you want a general assumption, you will get a general reply which will be of no use to you.

Comment: Edited question to include more details

Comment: Can you paste in all the includes? Also, Google-ing your first error showed me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340557/magento-prototype-error - have you tried it?

Comment: Edited question to include more details. Errors are pointing to third party JS extensions, while they work fine before I attempt to include these 3 JS files for this panel.

Comment: Thanks Fraccus. I am still not having an idea of how to do the fix you mentioned. Should I put var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); on top of the jquery file?

Comment: No, I it's already there, as per the `$j` in your error log. Was asking if you added it in or if the plugin ships with it. Can you DM a link to your site? Is it publicly accessible?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add these Cdn's.I hope these will work fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would including jQuery UI fix their issues?

Comment: Because these errors are a reason of less functions in the normal jquery files.This UI one file have some important functions that are purely programmed for animations

Comment: I strongly disagree. The user have an issue with a specific plugin. By posting a solution to replace their preferred plugin with what you deem easier, is not a solution. Regardless, the user is struggling with jQuery conflicts, adding MORE jQuery third party apps will not solve their issue.